# How can I perform filtering/searching school by writing the email address in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I would like to implement filtering/searching the university by typing its name like this picture below using flutter as a beginner. I would like it to auto-filter then display the school name even when I don't type the whole email address. It is quite hard to find good examples for what I want to do. Does anyone know of good examples that implemented something like I want?

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a simple search in list items based on the text written. Below is the solution i use to search items in a list and update the list accordingly.

Assume you have a list of Emails.
List emails = [];    A list which consist of emails from server/source

List emailsToShow = [];  List of emails you update with every letter typed.

```
searchEmail(String typedLetters) {
if (typedLetters.length > 0) {
  emailsToShow.clear();

  emailsToShow.addAll(emails
      .where((element) =>
          element.toLowerCase().contains(typedLetters.toLowerCase()))
      .toList());
     setState((){});

      }
  }
```

Now call this function from onChanged method of TextField and show emailsToShow list in ListView/ListView.builder and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will give it a shot! Will the list of emails stored in a separate dart file?

Comment: You can store it or just initialise it with json data you get from server.